# showing $\log(X_i)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for log normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

So let $X_1,X_2,..,X_N$ be an independent sample from log normal distribution with the pdf $f(x,\theta)=(x^2 \sigma^2*2\pi)^{(-1/2)}e^{-(log(x)-\theta)^2/{2\sigma^2}}$

where the parameter $\theta$ is uknown and $\sigma^2=1$

Show that
$\log(X_i)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$
that the log of the random variable $X_i$ is normally distributed. Not sure how to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one ways to do this. One that might be relatively easy is the CDF method.

Let $Y = log(X_i)$. The goal here will be to show that the pdf of $Y$ is that of a normal distribution via the pdf.

\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{d}{dy} P(Y \leq y)\\
&= \frac{d}{dy} P(\log(X_i) \leq y)\\
&= \frac{d}{dy} P(X_i \leq \exp(y))\\
&= f_{X_i}(\exp(y))\times \exp(y)
\end{align*}

Now we have expressed the pdf of $Y$ in terms of the pdf of $X_i$ which you have. Now you simply have to plug it in and you should be able to see that the result is a standard normal pdf.

Comment: so you simply plug in $e^y$ into the log normal distribution and this will show that is it a standard normal

Comment: what about the other $e^y$ outside of the $f_{xi}(e^y)$

Comment: You evaluate the expression I wrote, which includes the $\exp(y)$. It will cancel out though.

Comment: so you would end up having $(e^{2y}\sigma^2 2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-(y-\theta)^2/2\sigma^2} *e^{y}$

Comment: $f_{X_i}(\exp(y))exp(y) = ((e^y)^2 \sigma^2 2\pi)^\frac{-1}{2}\exp(-(y - \theta)^2/2\sigma^2)exp(y) = \frac{e^y}{e^y}  (\sigma^2 2\pi)^\frac{-1}{2}\exp(-(y - \theta)^2/2\sigma^2) = (\sigma^2 2\pi)^\frac{-1}{2}\exp(-(y - \theta)^2/2\sigma^2)$